# Wrap Text or Add Padding to Not Touch Video Edges with Moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

The code below is working fine to display two sets of text from a CSV.
E.G.

> This is the first text to display,This is the second text to display

At the moment though the text goes right up to the left and right edges of the video.

**How can either add padding to the edges of the video, or wrap the text to leave a gap on the left and right side of the video?**

I have tried a bunch of options but can't get the positioning right. I don't know if the solution should be adding a padding element, or custom text wrapping. I haven't added my attempts to get it to work as I've tried to many options, below is the working code without any side padding.

```
                with open('text.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                    text_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                    for j, row in enumerate(text_reader):
                        if j == i:
                            text1 = row[0]
                            text_clip1 = TextClip(text1, fontsize=50, color='white', font="Roboto-Bold.ttf", align='Center', method='caption', size=clip.size, stroke_color='black', stroke_width=1)
                            text_clip1 = text_clip1.set_position(('center', 'bottom')).set_start(2).set_duration(4)
                            if len(row) > 1:
                                text2 = row[1]
                                text_clip2 = TextClip(text2, fontsize=50, color='white', font="Roboto-Bold.ttf", align='Center', method='caption', size=clip.size, stroke_color='black', stroke_width=1)
                                text_clip2 = text_clip2.set_position(('center', 'bottom')).set_start(7).set_duration(4)
                                text_clip = mymovie.CompositeVideoClip([text_clip1, text_clip2])
                            else:
                                text_clip = text_clip1
                            clip = mymovie.CompositeVideoClip([clip, text_clip])
```

Answer (score 0):

A little to late but I just came across the same problem. Since I did not find any suitable answer I implemented a little helper function. It is not perfect, but it gets the job done.

```
import textwrap
from PIL import ImageFont

def soft_wrap_text(
    text: str, 
    fontsize: int, 
    letter_spacing: int, 
    font_family: str, 
    max_width: int,
):
    # Note that font_family has to be an absolut path to your .ttf/.otf
    image_font = ImageFont.truetype(font_family, fontsize) 

    # I am not sure my letter spacing calculation is accurate
    text_width = image_font.getlength(text) + (len(text)-1) * letter_spacing 
    letter_width = text_width / len(text)

    if text_width < max_width:
        return text

    max_chars = max_width / letter_width
    wrapped_text = textwrap.fill(text, width=max_chars)
    return wrapped_text
```

And then in your actual code:

```
clip = VideoFileClip(...)

wrap_title = helper.soft_wrap_text(
    'A very long "Hello World" text which would go out of screen',
    font_family="path/to/your/font/roboto.ttf",
    fontsize=69,
    letter_spacing=12,
    max_width=clip.w * .8  # *0.8 for some padding
)

txt_clip_title = TextClip(
    wrap_title,
    fontsize=69,
    color="white",
    bg_color='black',
    font="roboto",
    kerning=12,  # Letter spacing
    size=(1080, 1920),
)
```

Hope this helps ;-)